# Why $.get and then $("tag").prepend(dom) doesnt work?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to jQuery, HTML and JS. I'n trying to read file with html content and then add it to current page.
If I write

```
$("body").prepend("<table><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>");
```

everything will be ok, but

```
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL("file.txt"), function(data) { 
  $("body").prepend(data);
})
```

rises and error `Error in event handler for 'undefined': undefined` (Chrome). File.txt contains `<table><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>`. If file.txt will contain `<b>hello</b>` it will be added correctly.

Comment: `console.log( data );` inside the callback... Is it the correct string? Is it `undefined`?

Comment: what do you get if you alert chrome.extension.getURL("file.txt") outside the $.get method? Is it undefined?

Comment: here - http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/233/console.gif/ - what is displayed at console

Comment: `$("body").prepend(data.firstChild);` solved the problem and generated new - next call `data.firstChild` returns null. So `$("body").prepend(data.firstChild);` modifies data object. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `$.get('path', function(data) { }, 'text')`  (`, 'text'` added)